# Using "For" and "To" interchangeably

Tags: prepositions, difference, confusable

This question always confused me and finally I decided to know which one is correct and wrong!

Can we use "for" and "to" interchangeably?

**for example:**

> He always goes to the confectionery to buy some cake

And

> He always goes to the confectionery for buying some cake

Comment: No, you can't normally use the two words interchangeably. In your specific case, the second version is at the very least non-standard, if not formally "ungrammatical".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Prepositions often have *overlapping* usages, but that's not quite the same as "interchangeable". In your examples, notice how you had to switch the form of the word *buy* to make both sentences sound okay.

Both *for* and *to* can be used to **explain a reason or motivation for something**. However, when used in this way, *to* is followed by a verb, but *for* is followed by a noun. Consider:

> She goes to the spa on Friday **to** relax.
> She goes to the span on Friday **for** relaxation.

---

Here's another interesting example:

> The library is a good place **for** study.
> The library is a good place **to** study.

In this case, the sentences are the identical except for the preposition. However, does this mean the two words are interchangeable? No, it doesn't! These two sentences are both acceptable only because *study* can function as a noun **or** as a verb. So, in the first sentence, *study* functions as a noun, aligning with meanings 8a at [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/study):

> **study** (*n.*)
> the act or process of studying

In the second sentence, the two-word phrase *to study* functions as an infinitive, and therefore *study* is used as a verb, meaning:

> **study** (*v.*)
> to apply the mind to the learning or understanding of (a subject), esp by reading

---

I agree with some of the comments about your two sentences; that is, I think "to buy some cake" sounds better than "for buying some cake." But I can see why you'd be confused by this, because we can find some very similar sentences in published books, like:

> See if the hotel has a specified area [for walking your dog](https://books.google.com/books?id=u5eiAwAAQBAJ).
>
> Nurses have evaluated a variety of products and methods [for bathing older adults](https://books.google.com/books?id=yUx01gmNLboC).
>
> The whole procedure [for getting a license](https://books.google.com/books?id=yJSVZkBS7qgC) is rather complicated and requires a lot of time.

We could change those sentences to read: *to walk your dog, to bathe older adults*, and *to get a license*; any differences in meaning would be minimal. However, sometimes such changes will sound natural and acceptable, and sometimes they won't.

---

Most importantly, remember that little words like *for, in, of, at, with, on,* and *to* are extremely flexible. They typically have several meanings and are used in various ways, including phrasal verbs and prepositional phrases. It will be difficult, if not impossible, to pick two of these words, and give you foolproof guidance that will help you know "which one is correct and wrong." When it comes to these little words, there are simply too many variations to explain everything succinctly.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases; no. Off the top of my head, I can't think of any situations where they are interchangeable. In these two sentences, the one that has "to" is the most correct.